# Embedding some content of Remote Website in Titanium application

Tags: javascript, android, ios, titanium

I am trying to show some particular content of remote webpage in my App as I am using Titanium Appcelerator but i am unable to do this as I want to add those content of any website like Amazon.com which I have required I do not want to show unnecessary content in my app. Kindly please give me some guidance so that I can continue my work.

As I have done to show full webpage of cnn.com in a webview but I want to show its particular content in my own formatted views.

But I have to show its some particular content... Kindly help me out

Answer (score 1):

**Not possible.**

You cannot scrape a part of a website into your webview, because webview needs urls 
and I haven't heard of part urls till now. Have you?

Comment: yeah it is possible but i dont know how to work.

Comment: True, you cannot scrape part of a website. But you can run some of your own JavaScript after the page loads. You could then inject some styles to hide certain parts of the UI. Or some JavaScript to remove some elements. It's very brittle, and should concern the crap out of your users (Why am I using this app to get at Amazon.com? What's stopping the app maker from stealing every keystroke I make?). But it is possible. So take that, "closed as not a real question".